# entering values in a search bar to web scrape via python imported into a dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to search for details using id's from an excel file that has been imported via pandas. I am trying to loop through each of these values and search and extract information. The code is working fine until i reach the search bar. Once i reach the search option it is not capturing the values from the dataframe to go forward.

```
import pandas as pd
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

# reading the IDS excel file - with the changes made to see this code works
eid = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\lykerena\\Desktop\\IDS.xlsx',
                        sheet_name = 'IDS',
                        header = 0,
                        index_col = 0)
ids = eid['ids']

chrome_driver = 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe'
url = 'url'
username = '123'
password = 'abc'


def get_driver():
    try:
        return webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
    except:
        return webdriver.Firefox


def my_id_login(username, password, url):
    driver = get_driver()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtUserName').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtPassword').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnLogin').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()

# loop to search based on the id's provided - Changes made so this code could work 
for i in ids(): 
   #search bar
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(i)
    #click search
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_pnlAgentEmprSearch"]/center').click()




print(my_id_login(username,password,url))
print(ids)
```

values not being entered in data frame. Could you let me know what do i need to improve the code. I just have one column in my file that is ids. I need to download the joining date and the date the associate started production work. I am stuck since the search bar is not taking in the values.

Regards,

Ren.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `driver.get(url)` instead of `driver.get('url')`?

Comment: Yes it is driver get(url) . I had my actual URL in IT. The issue is not with the URL.  The search bar is not taking values to begin the search.

Comment: Adding the code that i made changes to make my above code. work. in the above section itself. Unable to indent to show the changes here. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. The above section has the updated code. That is working great.